# Sorry this site has not been shared with you

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Windows Standard 2012 R2

SharePoint Foundation 2013

SQL Server 2014

I have a SharePoint Application page that is throwing the above error when clicking on any Button on the page. I even added a button with nothing in the method and still get the above error.

Note that I am NOT challenged when accessing the Application page initially and am NOT challenged when clicking the button. None of the code in the original method gets executed. In fact, it appears that the page cycle is never processed. I have logging in the method, the page_load even and in the page_unload event and nothing is logged.

The site is configured for claims authentication and I have verified that my account, application service account are both in Owners and both are admins on the box. Application Service account has SYSadmin on the SQL server (also located on the same box).

I changed SharePoint to allow access requests and to send me an email for those requests. Now the page shows:

```
   The website declined to show this webpage

   HTTP 403 


    Most likely causes:
    •This website requires you to log in.
```

Any suggestions?

One more thing: this is a one-page application. There are no redirects, etc. within the page/application.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a permissions issue for the application service account. Never could find out specifically where but reverted to a previous service account and it works now.